How to do a wxPython Slider.SetValue w/o triggering event handler
I want to programmatically set the value of a slider after the control has been

created
displayed,
and the EVT_SLIDER handler has been bound.

Is there a way to avoid triggering the handler when programmatically doing
Slider.SetValue()

?
I looked for an API Flag.  No luck

You clearly missed this https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.Slider.html#wx.Slider.SetValue

Doing that call triggers the callback

Process wxEVT_SLIDER which is generated after any change of wx.Slider position in addition to one of the events above. The answer probably lies with not binding EVT_SLIDER, instead use EVT_SCROLL_CHANGED or a combination of other events, just not EVT_SLIDER or EVT_SCROLL

I do NOT want to generate an event when calling the method AND the event handler is bound

Of course it is bound, other wise you would not be having this issue. My point was that you might try binding to some other slider event/s to catch changes. (Other than wx.EVT_SLIDER) The first part of my previous comment is a quote, direct from the manual. So it generates that event, no matter what! If you need anything more than advice, you should provide a code sample, emulating what you are trying to achieve, then we can experiment with that.

Thank you for clarifying I understand now.  That is a good idea.  Also, you are correct I should have posted a code snippet.
